# My app keeps crashing (Fatal exception)

Tags: android, android-studio, crash, android-tablayout, crash-reports

my app opens with splash screen normally but cant proceed to home screen and crashes ! 
i'm trying to make tablayout (there is no error in code)

this is the error through debugging :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.foot.ws.worldcup, PID: 10249
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.foot.ws.worldcup/com.foot.ws.worldcup.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2904)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:835)
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>                      Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:422)
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2665)
>                         at com.foot.ws.worldcup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6986)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1232)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:835)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
>                         at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
>                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout.(AppBarLayout.java:158)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:422) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2665) 
>                         at com.foot.ws.worldcup.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6986) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1232) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2857) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1643) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:835)

and this is the main : (imports included)

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
    appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbarid);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentQuiz(),"Quiz");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentExplore(), "Explore");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentStore(), "Store");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}}
```

xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/appbarid">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/tabtextcolor"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabindicatorcolor"
    android:background="@color/tab"/>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
    >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: are you importing appbarLayout from support library in MainActivity  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define theme in the **AndroidManifest.xml** for your application like:

```
<application
.....
        android:theme="@style/Theme">
```

And defined this style in **values/styles.xml** file like:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
.....
</style>
```