# Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer?

Tags: java, android

I tried everything but cannot seem to solve this error. All the solutions I am finding are for pre-androidx codes. I think I added all dependencies needed, but it still would not work. I have also updated my android studio and all the dependencies to their most recent version. Any help would be appreciated. Below are code snippets from my Android Studio Project:

**Logcat**

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2019-11-06 16:01:16.819 5559-5559/com.example.scientificcalculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scientificcalculator, PID: 5559
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scientificcalculator/com.example.scientificcalculator.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.scientificcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable android:color/primary_text_light with resource ID #0x1060003
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060003
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:768)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:600)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:885)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:953)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:67)
2019-11-06 16:01:16.825 5559-5559/com.example.scientificcalculator E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:749)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:659)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:552)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.scientificcalculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflateChildElements(StateListDrawable.java:189)
        at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:122)
        at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableInflater.inflateFromXmlForDensity(DrawableInflater.java:142)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInnerForDensity(Drawable.java:1295)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlForDensity(Drawable.java:1254)
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:758)
```

**Build.Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scientificcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/javaluator-3.0.3.jar')
}
```

**Styles**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.scientificcalculator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation files('libs/javaluator-3.0.3.jar')
}
```

**Color**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="calculator_background">#2196F3</color>
    <color name="calculator_foreground">#135ba3</color>
    <color name="calculator_color">#d9dfe4</color>
    <color name="calculator_screen">#d1e3e7</color>
    <color name="icons">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="divider">#B6B6B6</color>
    <color name="primary_text">#212121</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: show the xml code since the error occurs when inflating.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51864498/my-app-keeps-crashing-fatal-exception and as @ZohaibAmir said xml I think Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #18: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable this line

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! Updated my post with the xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this line in your log:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable
>   android:color/primary_text_light with resource ID #0x1060003
>        Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/color/primary_text_light.xml from drawable resource ID #0x1060003

It seems that 'primary_text_light.xml' does not exist or cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. So I started a new empty project without my own code at all. The same error! There was only one xml-file and it had only 18 lines, but `logcat` complains on `line#27`!

So I merely **upgraded gradle** and empty app loaded on real device successfully.

- Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch1 for Windows 64
- Android Gradle Plugin version 7.2.1
- Gradle version 7.3.3